# How prove this $\measuredangle AGH=\measuredangle BGH$.

Tags: geometry

Let $ABC$ be a triangle, and let $D$, $A$, $B$, $E$ be points on line $AB$, in that order, such that $AC=AD$ and $BE=BC$. Let $\omega_1, \omega_2$ be the circumcircles of $\triangle ABC$ and $\triangle CDE$, respectively, which meet at a point $F \neq C$.  If the tangent to $\omega_2$ at $F$ cuts $\omega_1$ again at $G$, and the foot of the altitude from $G$ to $FC$ is $H$, prove that $\measuredangle AGH=\measuredangle BGH$.
[image]

my  idea:
note
$$\measuredangle GFC=\measuredangle GBC=\measuredangle FEC$$
and $$\measuredangle FGA=180^{\circ}-\measuredangle FBA$$
$$\measuredangle CGB=\measuredangle CFB=180^{\circ}-\measuredangle CAB$$
since 
$$AC=AD,\Longrightarrow \measuredangle ADC=\dfrac{180^{\circ}-\measuredangle CAB}{2}=\dfrac{1}{2}\measuredangle CFB$$

since from cyclic quadrilateral $D,E,C,F$

then 
$$\measuredangle CFE=\measuredangle ADC=\dfrac{1}{2}\measuredangle CFB$$
and
$$\measuredangle CFB=\measuredangle CFE+\measuredangle BFE\Longrightarrow \measuredangle BFE=\dfrac{1}{2}\measuredangle CFB$$

This problem is from http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?p=3151966&sid=694e3ee0bae3c04d9d208b3190e920d0#p3151966

I want to take advantage of the following figure to prove, there is something wrong with the proof of the website

Comment: What are your thoughts about this problem?

Comment: Since some of your questions have been more like conjectures, I find myself compelled to ask: *Are you sure the result is true?* (Noting that a problem comes from a textbook, a contest, a website, or some other source, would be helpful.)

Comment: Yes, I have edit,Thank you

Comment: From the beginning we have problems. You wrote "...let $D$, $A$, $B$, $E$ be points on line $AB$, in that order..." . Well, this is **not** what is shown in the diagram.